# Error while loading a library in function which is defined in view

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

There is a function which is defined in view page.

```
function name "managedepartment()"

 switch($page)
    {
        case "manage_department":{
                echo '<h1 class="page-header">';
                echo $pagehead;

                echo '</h1>';
                managedepartment($hod_list);break;

            }
        default:show_404();
    }
        /////////////////////////////////

function managedepartment($hod_list){
    $this->load->helper('uri');
    echo $this->uri->segment(1);

    }
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context ...
```

Is there is any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try this code . You use **$CI =& get_instance();** .

```
switch($page)
                    {
                        case "manage_department":{
                            echo '<h1 class="page-header">';
                            echo $pagehead;

                            echo '</h1>';
                            $CI =& get_instance();
                            $CI->managedepartment($hod_list);break;

                        }
                        default:show_404();
                    }
    /////////////////////////////////
```

You Declare this function in your controller

```
   function managedepartment($hod_list){
   $this->load->helper('uri');
   echo $this->uri->segment(1);

 }
```

now working fine